# What to do if I don't have Context?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing my first app in Android Studio. I have two classes. One which contains settings.

```
public class settings {
    private int przed_termin;
    private int przed_po_otwarciu;
    private boolean powiadomienia;
    private ustawienia_sql ustawienia_baza;
}
```

And a second one which is responsible for reading and saving them to SQLite database. And now I'm trying to create object `settings_sql` in `settings`, but to do that I need a `Context`. And is there possibility to get past that?

```
public class settings_sql extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public settings_sql (Context context) {
        super(context, "ustawienia.db", null, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: to just save those few values use SharedPrefernces

Comment: Either pass the context as a a parameter or get it from your base Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give you a bit of understand then code. Context is a common frustration for new Android programmers.

There's actually 4 different types of Context objects. This important to know. Generally if you're doing user controls you'll want the Activity context the user control is hosted in. daylight's answer will work for that. Basically the context object is an Activity object. There's also Service instance objects that have a Service Context.

Another Context type is Application Context.

This is how you make sure any class in your app has access to the Application Context:

Create a class like this. That statically stores a reference to it's self with an accessor:

```
public class MyApp extends Application{
    private static Context applicationContext;

    public void onCreate() {
        applicationContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Modify your ApplicationManifest.xml to include the name attribute in your application tag:

```
<application
    android:name="MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity......
</application>
```

Then wherever you need a context object and don't have one convient use:

```
MyApp.getApplicationContext()
```

For example:

```
settings_sql(MyApp.getApplicationContext());
```

Because you create in the application class oncreate event you can be assured it'll never be null, while in your app.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend passing the Context to classes that need it. You already have your `settings_sql(Context context)` constructor, which is a good start.

In your main application code, you can easily pass the Context from either your activity or application, depending on your needs and also on the actual lifetime of the `settings_sql` object. Does this object need to live beyond the duration of a single Activity?

If you then decide to write tests, you are free from depending on a static variable held in an arbitrary class that may not have much to do with your test. Why would a local unit test need to know about the `Application` class, for example?

You might not run into this problem early on, or at all, and a static variable may be a perfectly workable short-term solution, but just be aware that this can make things awkward and difficult to reason about when you're interacting with parts of your system from within limited scopes, particularly tests.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity do something like:

```
private static Context context;

public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
```

Then when you make the call just pass the context in.

Comment: its meant in nonActivity situation

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to have an Application class in your APK and add a static method to it to retrieve the context, like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static MyApplication sInstance = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return sInstance.getApplicationContext();
}
```